# Shell Script Appending Ignores Variables

Tags: jquery, bash, shell

could really use some help with an assignment.
What I am trying to do is write a program in Terminal, without using any editors. When appending to the file to write it, every time there is a $x, it gets ignored and only appends the rest of the code.

```
echo $test hello >> sample.sh
```

Only appends

```
hello
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want [shell expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) use single quotes:

```
echo '$test hello' >> sample.sh
```

otherwise `$test` will be considered a variable and will be converted to it's actual value.